# How can I use youtube-dl script in my ios application?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, youtube-dl

How can I use [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html) script in my ios application? Script can be in two forms:

1. multiple *.py script files
2. one executable file "youtube-dl" (It may run in the terminal as a simple command)

I have embedded python library in project (as framework):

```
#include <Python/Python.h>
```

How do I run the youtube-dl script in the application?

Comment: Offtopic: If you intend to put your app in the app store, I'm pretty sure Apple won't allow you to do this, since it's against the terms of youtube.

Comment: @Claude we do not download youtube video. We just play them on the video player.

Comment: Hi, Just wondering if you ever figured out a good way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to play videos from Youtube use https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit

To use the library you just need to know VideoID YouTube:

```
XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:@"9bZkp7q19f0"];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
```

Comment: We need to play videos not only from YouTube but also from other sites

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my code at https://github.com/kewlbear/YoutubeDL.  It's Swift code, but I think it can be helpful.